# Why does docker-compose use ~60GB to build this image

Tags: django, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose

When I start `docker-compose build` I have 60 gigs free. I run out of space before it finishes. Any idea what could possibly be going on?

I'm running latest of Docker for Mac and docker-compose

here's my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.6-alpine
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

  web:
    image: python:3.6-alpine
    command: ./waitforit.sh solr:8983 db:5432 -- bash -c "./init.sh"
    build: .
    env_file: ./.env
    volumes:
      - .:/sark
      - solrcores:/solr
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    links:
      - db
      - solr
    restart: always

  solr:
    image: solr:6-alpine
    ports:
      - 8983:8983
    entrypoint:
      - docker-entrypoint.sh
      - solr-precreate
      - sark
    volumes:
      - solrcores:/opt/solr/server/solr/mycores

volumes:
  data:
  solrcores:
```

and my dockerfile for the "web" image:

```
FROM python:3

# Some stuff that everyone has been copy-pasting
# since the dawn of time.
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Install some necessary things.
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y swig libssl-dev dpkg-dev netcat

# Copy all our files into the image.
RUN mkdir /sark
WORKDIR /sark
COPY . /sark/

# Install our requirements.
RUN pip install -U pip
RUN pip install -Ur requirements.txt
```

This image itself when built is ~3 gigs.

I'm pretty flummoxed.

Comment: Well we have no idea what is in the current directory (where the `dockrr-compose.yml` file is). The entire contents of that directory are sent to the docker daemon when you build. It sounds like you might need to look into a `.dockerignore` file to only send the intended context.

Comment: Add the output of below commands `du -sh .`, `df -h` and `mount`

Comment: The project folder (the "." context for docker-compose) is 4 gigs. I have 73 gigs free. Not sure why you need mount output.

Comment: It could certainly use a .dockerignore -- I'll add one and see what happens

Comment: Adding a reasonable .dockerignore file has resolved the issue. Though I'm still at a loss as to why docker would require >60gb to build an image out of a 4gb folder. Unless there was some kind of recursive wonkiness going on.

Comment: @Walker, if you share the outputs then I would give you an explanation as to why

Comment: Because everything in the current folder of the `Dockerfile` is copied to the build context to build the image, regardless if the files are used or not. The `.dockerignore` file allows you to ignore sending certain files to the build context. The first part of the Builder usage documentation has some more information about the build context that I'd recommend reading: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#usage.